# What does bar means in ggplot geom="bar"? I am confused with stat="identity"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question about the ggplot2 package.
Using the diamonds data, I can't tell the difference in the following three groups of code.

```
qplot(color, data = diamonds, geom = "bar")

qplot(color, data = diamonds, geom = "bar", weight = carat) +
scale_y_continuous("carat")

qplot(color, carat, data=diamonds, geom="bar",
      stat = "identity", position = "identity") + 
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 0):

The first plot shows the number of diamonds (counts) with each color.

The second one weights the diamonds by carat. That is it shows the total carat of each color.

The last figure just shows the heaviest diamond in each color category. This has nothing to do with stat="identity". The default position is position="stack". Instead of stacking, position="identity" plots the carat of each diamond on top of each other and you only see the largest one.